# Scala PDFBox error in code

Tags: java, scala, pdfbox

Wrote a function for reading text from a PDF document.
Used scala language, Selenium, PDFBox 2.0.1.

Below is the code:

```
enter code here
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.{FirefoxBinary, FirefoxDriver, FirefoxProfile}
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
def pdfreaddata {
  driver.get("https://www.....pdf")
  driver.manage.timeouts.implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  val url: URL = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl)
  println(url)
  val fileToParse: BufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream())
  val parser: PDFParser = new PDFParser(fileToParse)
  parser.parse()
  val output: String = new PDFTextStripper().getText(parser.getPDDocument)
  println("pdf Value" + output)
  parser.getPDDocument.close()

  driver.manage.timeouts.implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

Showing error for PDFParser in `val parser: PDFParser = new PDFParser(fileToParse)`

Error message:

> Cannot resolve constructor

Tried the code in Java too, getting same error.

Comment: Correct call is PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(stream). Using new PDFParser() is an outdated method. However I don't know if that is the cause of your troubles.

Answer (score 1):

You are using PDFBox version 2.x, however you are obviously following the docs for version 1.x . In 2.0 there is no such constructor. Some things have changed, including parsing. Follow the [migration guide](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html) or fall back to 1.8, since it does look much more documented and with more material online.

Answer (score 0):

Using pdfbox 1.8.12 solved the constructor issue. But even the pdf's was not password protected, it was showing as encrypted. Below is the final code using Scala to extract encrypted text from a pdf document. Might be useful for someone in future.

```
def pdfreaddata {
driver.get("https://www....combo.pdf")
driver.manage.timeouts.implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
val url: URL = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl)
println(url)
val fileToParse: BufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream())
val parser: PDFParser = new PDFParser(fileToParse)
parser.parse()
val cosDocument:COSDocument  = parser.getDocument()
val pdDocument:PDDocument = new PDDocument(cosDocument)
if(pdDocument.isEncrypted()) {
  val sdm: StandardDecryptionMaterial  = new StandardDecryptionMaterial(PDF_OWNER_PASSWORD)//PDF_OWNER_PASSWORD =""
  pdDocument.openProtection(sdm) 
}
val output: String = new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdDocument)
println("pdf Value" + output)
parser.getPDDocument.close()

driver.manage.timeouts.implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
}
```

Comment: File can be encrypted with a empty user password, that is why. This happens quite often and is to restrict permissions (e.g. forbid text extraction, printing, etc)